# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, while using Kfold cross Validation

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to use `Kfold` cross valiadtion for my model, but get this error while doing so. I know that `KFold` only accepts 1D arrays but even after converting the length input to an array its giving me this problem.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier, RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold

if __name__ == "__main__":
  np.random.seed(1335)

  verbose = True
  shuffle = False
  n_folds = 5

  y = np.array(y)

  if shuffle: 
    idx = np.random.permutation(y.size)
    X_train = X_train[idx]
    y = y[idx]

  skf = KFold(y, n_folds) 

  models = [RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1, criterion='gini'),ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1, criterion='entropy')]

  print("Stacking in progress")
  A = []
  for j, clf in enumerate(models):
     print(j, clf)

     for i, (itrain, itest) in enumerate(skf):
        print("Fold :", i)
        x_train = X_train[itrain]
        x_test = X_train[itest]
        y_train = y[itrain]
        y_test = y[itest]
        print(x_train.shape, x_test.shape)

        print(len(x_train), len(x_test))

        clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
        pred = clf.predict_proba(x_test)
        A.append(pred)
```

I get the error for the line "`skf = KFold(y, n_folds)`". Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: How is `y` defined? Also, your example should be minimal: is it really useful to include 4 classifiers?

Comment: y is defined as the target variable of the Training set. No its not I will edit it.

Comment: So no more need for models and the j loop too :) a simple example is easier for us to understand and makes it quicker to spot the error. See my answer on the use of KFold.

Answer (score 1):

From [its doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold), `KFold()` does not expect `y` as an input, but only the number of splits (n_folds).

Once you have an instance of `KFold`, you do `myKfold.split(x)` (`x` being all of your input data) to obtain an iterator yielding train and test indices. Example copy pasted from sklearn doc:

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
>>> kf.get_n_splits(X)
2
>>> print(kf)  
KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
>>> for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
...    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
TRAIN: [2 3] TEST: [0 1]
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
```